# Очень странная ошибка - "} expected", см.скриншот

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Проект работал, а потом вдруг перестал. Ошибка простая, что даже смешно, я уже 100 раз всё проверил - всё правильно расставлено. Этой ошибки не было и код в этом месте я давно не трогал, а потом вдруг появился error во время ctrl+shift+b.

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: ничего не странно. убери else который за ним идет и будет работать

Comment: Большое спасибо, просто спас) Не знаю откуда он взялся, если хочешь - можешь ответ написать, + к репутации будет

Comment: @Grundy можешь ответ написать, + к карме)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно убрать `else`, а просто оставить `if` и тогда всё будет работать.